# error: conversion from std::chrono::time_point float to non-scalar type long int requested

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have this code that tries to create a new time_point by adding a duration:

```
// now
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
// duration
std::chrono::duration<float> duration(1.0f / 60.0f); // float in seconds
// now + duration
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point futureTime = now + duration;
```

But it gives me this error

```
error: conversion from 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >' to non-scalar type 'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >}' requested
# it's over there in the distance --->

# ... again, with some manual formatting:
error:
    conversion from
    'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock,
                             std::chrono::duration<float, 
                                                   std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >'
    to non-scalar type
    'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point
     {aka 
     std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock,
                             std::chrono::duration<long int,
                                                   std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >}'
    requested
```

After some heavy squinting there's a `float` in the first one and a `long int` in the second. Thus `now (long int) + duration (float)` gives a time_point with some internal floating point duration and I'm presumably asking for it to be stuffed back into the default `long int` representation.

I'd like to eventually pass this time point to `std::condition_variable::wait_until`. How can I force the conversion to a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`?

What kind of precision will I lose if I do (i.e. is it storing milliseconds in which case I'll lose some of my 1 / 60)?

If I don't convert it, what's a nice short way of writing the type that `now + duration` returns (yes I could use auto but for the sake of say passing it to a function)?

Comment: "*is it storing milliseconds*" It stores what you ask it to store. Also, if you want to wait for 1/60th of a second, is there some reason why you can't just use `wait_for`, since that's exactly its purpose?

Comment: Sidenote: it can be annoying to make stuff to happen in 1/60ths of a second in Windows because Windows uses a 1/64 tick.

Comment: @NicolBolas `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` seems to implicitly use nanoseconds with `std::ratio<1, 1000000000>`. I haven't asked it to do this. I would like to wait until 1/60th of a second has passed and with `wait_until` I can keep calling it until it times out if I'm interrupted, unlike wait_for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The analysis you have done in your question is basically correct.  And there are a couple of good ways to make this work.<sup>1</sup>, <sup>2</sup>

### Use `auto`

```
// now
system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
// duration
duration<float> duration(1.0f / 60.0f); // float in seconds
// now + duration
auto futureTime = now + duration;
```

The type of `futureTime` is a `time_point<system_clock, duration<float, nano>>`.  That is, it is a `time_point` based on `system_clock`, storing `nanoseconds` represented by a `float`.

This type can be used with `std::condition_variable::wait_until`.

### Cast `now + duration` back to `system_clock::time_point`:

```
// now
system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
// duration
duration<float> duration(1.0f / 60.0f); // float in seconds
// now + duration
system_clock::time_point futureTime =
    time_point_cast<system_clock::duration>(now + duration);
```

`time_point_cast<duration>` is how you cast `time_point`s.  You have to explicitly specify the type of duration you want the resulting `time_point` to have.  The resultant `time_point` will continue to be based on the same clock.
The result will be truncated (rounded towards zero) to the next integral `system_clock::duration` (`nanoseconds` on this platform).

This type can be used with `std::condition_variable::wait_until`.

### Round `now + duration` back to `system_clock::time_point`:

```
system_clock::time_point futureTime = round<system_clock::duration>(now + duration);
```

This is just like the previous solution except this rounds to the nearest integral `nanoseconds`, and to the even `nanoseconds` on a tie.  `std::chrono::round` is available in C++17 and later.  This will give a result at most `1ns` different than `time_point_cast`.

If you don't have C++17 but still want to use `round`, feel free to use [this one](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html).

This type can be used with `std::condition_variable::wait_until`.

### Represent 1/60 *exactly* with integral arithmetic

```
// now
system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
// duration
duration<int, std::ratio<1, 60>> duration{1}; // 1/60 of a second
// now + duration
auto futureTime = now + duration;
```

It is common for people to say:

> It isn't possible to represent <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub> second precisely.

But you can with `<chrono>`. :-)  `duration<int, std::ratio<1, 60>>` counts in units of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub> of a second using a representation of `int`.  `duration{1}` is <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub> of a second.  `duration{2}` is <sup>2</sup>/<sub>60</sub> of a second.  Etc.

`auto` *really* comes in handy here.  The type of `futureTime` is: `time_point<system_clock, duration<system_clock::rep, ratio<1, 3'000'000'000>>>`.  Or in English:  A `time_point` based on `system_clock` using a duration with a representation type of whatever `system_clock::time_point` uses (typically `long long`) and a period of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> `nanoseconds`.

It turns out that <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> `nanoseconds` is the *coarsest* precision that can *exactly* represent both `system_clock::period` (`nanoseconds` on this platform) and <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub> of a second.

And `<chrono>` figures all of this out for you automatically.  All you have to do to take advantage of it is use `auto`.

This type can be used with `std::condition_variable::wait_until`.

One could also use `duration<int, std::ratio<1, 60>>` in combination with `time_point_cast` or `round` as shown earlier if you wanted to get back to the nanoseconds-based `system_clock::time_point`.

### Summary

Which is best?  You will have to decide that based on other factors in your application.  Typically what is best is whatever makes the rest of your code more readable.

But you've got options, and they are all good options.  And they will all work with `std::condition_variable::wait_until`.

As you explore your options, if it doesn't compile, that's because `<chrono>` is catching your errors at compile-time (just like the first one).  If it compiles (and if you haven't escaped the type-system with `.count()` or `.time_since_epoch()`), then it's working.

---

<sup>1</sup> The answers in this question assume `system_clock::duration` is `nanoseconds` as reported in the question.  This is only true with gcc, and is different on Windows and macOS.

<sup>2</sup> In order to not get lost in verbosity, I'm writing my answers as if there is a:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
```

in play.  It makes things *so* much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`std::condition_variable::wait_until` looks like this: ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until))

```
template< class Clock, class Duration >
std::cv_status
    wait_until( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock,
                const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timeout_time );

template< class Clock, class Duration, class Pred >    
bool wait_until( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock,
                 const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timeout_time,
                 Pred pred );
```

You can pass any `time_point<C, D>` to it. It doesn't have to be `system_clock::time_point`. And `system_clock::time_point` is just `time_point<system_clock>`.

The exact representation of the clocks is implementation-defined, but it has to be an integer type. It isn't possible to represent `(1/60)s` precisely with an integer as the number and second as the unit.

`now + duration`, where `now` is of type `time_point<C, D1>` and `duration` is of type `duration<R2, P2>`, is of type `time_point<C, std::common_type_t<duration<R1, P1>, D2>>`.